# Can I combine the PDFs for inference here?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have 2 independent floating lighthouses (A, B) on a one-dimensional endless sea. These emit a noisy light signal, the received strength of which depends only on distance (the bigger the distance between a lighthouse and a receiver, the weaker the signal). Having modelled this relationship (all lighthouses respect this common model) and given a received signal strength, I know the underlying symmetric PDF (total prob = 1) showing the probable receiver’s distance from that lighthouse. Symmetric because the signals are transmitted towards both (-∞ ,+∞) directions.

[Depiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CgGg.png)

In the depiction above, I have a rough prior belief that lighthouse B and lighthouse A are at those corresponding spots. My position (as a receiver) is at C, but I have no idea where this position is and thus, I have to use the received signals from the lighthouses to infer my position via the distances from the two lighthouses.

Assuming that from lighthouse B, I receive a weak signal (corresponding to pink PDF) and from lighthouse A, I receive a stronger signal (corresponding to blue PDF). Now, does it make sense to multiply these PDFs and then find where their product becomes maximum in order to infer the most probable position of mine (i.e. C)? Wouldn’t that be my best guess at least given my prior belief for the position of B and A?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

This is your best guess if you believe that these signal strengths are independent, or if you don't know anything about their dependence. It doesn't seem realistic, though, that they would be independent, since some of the potential noise sources would probably affect them in similar ways. If they're not independent and you can determine their joint distribution, that would give you a better guess at your position.